# ERROR- ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Tags: oracle, deadlock, trace

I got this error when running a procedure
I would like to know if it is possible to see the trace file on the server
about the details

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  A deadlock produces a trace file.  The database alert log will have the name of the incident-specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find such informations in the ***`alert<your_sid>.log`*** file. 
By `<your_sid>`, i mean the value when you issue `$ echo $ORACLE_SID` ( mostly set as this ).

It's under `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/<your_sid>/<your_sid>/trace` path location.

You may also see the value for *base* path by issuing

> `$ echo $ORACLE_BASE`( or alternatively, you would keep under
>   `$ORACLE_HOME` directory, instead ).

You can also query

> *`g`v$diag_info*
>   performance view ( `g` stands whether you have a `RAC` instance ) to see the path.